# Iterate over list of keys and add to Pandas DF if key present in given row/column

Tags: python, pandas, list, iteration

I have a fairly large (57k rows) data file I regularly access that contains personnel listings and their skill sets. I'd like to feed a keyword list and output a DF with only rows where those keys were present, like this:

```
key_list = ('LEAN', 'SIGMA', 'Toyota')

for key in key_list:
    df1 = df[df[col_key].str.contains(key, case=False)]

# col_key previously defined.
```

In the above case, I'll only get results with Toyota. To capture all keys I need to specify:

```
df1 = df[df[col_key].str.contains('sigma', case=False) |
    df[col_key].str.contains('LEAN', case=False) |
    df[col_key].str.contains('SIGMA', case=False) |
    df[col_key].str.contains('Toyota', case=False)]
```

Making it modular for whatever length of keys provided will enable turning around faster data asks. I feel as though I'm missing something silly. If there's a more efficient/Pythonic approach I'm all ears. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can check for each value if it contains any of the words in the key list, here an example:

```
df[df[col_key].apply(lambda x: any([word.lower() in x.lower() for word in key_list]))]
```

Comment: This worked great! Thank you very much. Being honest, I need to break this down to genuinely understand what's happening item by item, but I know enough to drop it in and my test data gave me the results I expected.